# PRNG not seeded (on SCO OpenServer 5.0.7 MP5)

Tags: ssh, random, openserver

On SCO OpenServer 5.0.7 MP5, upon attempting use of any ssh-based utility, the following is returned, and any intended SSH connection does not occur:

```
PRNG not seeded
```

How is this resolved (the condition persists across reboot)?

System start scripts appear identical between working and the non-working system.

The answer given for Linux and various UNIX is that one must verify existence of, or permissions assigned to, ***/dev/random*** and/or ***/dev/urandom***.  This UNIX does not have such devices on a working system, so these answers are unhelpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution became possible by searching various parts of the system for instances of **prng** in a case-insensitive manner.

Preliminary investigation reveals that on similarly configured systems, but where one works, and the other does not, the configuration appears identical, but on the non-working system, a ***in.prngd*** service is not running.

```
# ps -ef | grep prng
root 350 1 0 Mar-23 ? 00:00:11 /etc/in.prngd /etc/egd-pool
```

Between both systems, configuration files, scripts, and binaries, in or under ***/etc*** seemingly related to *prngd* have identical sums, and a system software verify shows no automatically correctable anomalies.

Start scripts under ***/etc/rc?.d/*** were identical, with *prngd* startup apparently handled by ***/etc/rc2.d/S85tcp***.  Examination of this file appears to indicate that the service is started by calling ***/etc/prngd***, and ***/var/adm/rc.log*** seems to show the system attempted to start the service.

```
Starting TCP services: prngd inetd snmpd sshd ntpd
```

Attempting to manually use ***/etc/prngd*** to query or start the service fails with a similar error:

```
# /etc/prngd query
/etc/prngd: ^X: bad number
```

A copy was made of ***/etc/prngd***, and *set -x* inserted:

```
...
+ get_server_pid
+ [ -r /etc/prngd.lock ]
+ read line
+ set -- junk
+ shift
+ return
/tmp/prngd: ^X: bad number
```

On the working system, ***/etc/prngd.lock*** is non-empty and contains the PID of the running in.prngd process.  On the non-working system, the file is empty.

The solution:

```
# rm -f /etc/prngd.lock
```